# How to enable crash reporting on Google Chromium on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I am using Google Chromium on Debian (the one in debian depository). I am hitting some bug, that crashes Chrome, but that I can replicate only in Chromium, not in Chrome. (It might be present in Chrome too, I just cannot replicate it.)

I can't figure out how to enable crash reporting in Chromium.

[This guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96817?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) doesn't work - I don't have that option in Advanced.

[image: Advanced]

[This guide](https://www.chromium.org/developers/crash-reports) describes:

> Linux
>
> Breakpad is compiled in, but is not enabled by default. See IsCrashReportingEnabled() in chrome_browser_main_linux.cc for details on when it is enabled.
>
> Set the gyp variable (GYP_DEFINES) linux_dump_symbols=1 to dump the debugging symbols for the chrome binary in the Breakpad symbol format as part of a build.

[chrome_browser_main_linux.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/chrome_browser_main_linux.cc?q=chrome_browser_main_linux.cc&sq=package:chromium&dr&l=90) does not have this function.

[breakpad_linux.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/crash/content/app/breakpad_linux.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr&l=2089) has a function `IsCrashReporterEnabled`, which is similar enough; however, I'm not too clever by staring at the code.

I am not sure what is gyp and if I have to use it. (I don't want to rebuild whole Chromium just to enable crash reporting.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enabling crash reporting on Chromium is not possible, since there are no official Chromium builds. Chromium is built by the distro maintainers (Debian, Red Hat) and it might or might not have the debug info.

The only builds Google does is Chrome from the Chrome website.